# Construction of Observer Coordinates in General Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

In *A First Course in General Relativity,* Second Edition, by Bernard Schutz, on the bottom of Page 8, he is expanding on the spacetime diagrams in Figure 1.5.

He states *"[...] the four angles are equal [...]",* referring to angles the moving frame axes have with respect to the non moving frame axes and vice versa.  However, nowhere does he demonstrate or prove that the  $\bar{x}$-axis makes and angle of $\theta$ with $x$-axis.

How is this proved or demonstrated?

Comment: Could you reproduce the figure in some way, instead of forcing others to go through the trouble of obtaining a copy of this book simply to answer your question?

Comment: Comment on question (v1): The four angels are certainly not all equal.  Some are significantly holier that others.

Answer (score 1):

This is the diagram in Schutz:

[image: Schutz1]

The claim is the angle $\phi$ is the same in all four places.

I'll prove this for one case - the angle between the $x$ and $x'$ axes in the left diagram. Proving it for the other cases is a straightforward extension of this and you might like to have a go for yourself. Let's start with an expanded diagram to make it clear what we're doing:

[image: Schutz2]

All points on the $x'$ axis have $t' = 0$ i.e. their coordinates are $(0, x')$. What we'll do is use the Lorentz transformations to tranform the point $(0, x')$ into the unprimed frame, and then we can use:

$$ \tan\phi = \frac{t}{x} \tag{1} $$

to get the angle $\phi$. The Lorentz transforms as normally written are:

$$\begin{align}
t' &= \gamma (t - \frac{vx}{c^2}) \\
x' &= \gamma (x - vt)
\end{align}$$

This transforms from the unprimed frame $S$ into the primed frame $S'$ that is moving with velocity $v$ relative to $S$. To do the tranformation $S' \rightarrow S$ we just replace $v$ by $-v$ because $S$ is moving with velocity $-v$ relative to $S'$. So we get:

$$\begin{align}
t &= \gamma (t' + \frac{vx'}{c^2}) \\
x &= \gamma (x' + vt')
\end{align}$$

Now if you feed the point $(0, x')$ into these equations you get the point in $S$:

$$\begin{align}
t &= \gamma \frac{vx'}{c^2} \\
x &= \gamma x'
\end{align}$$

and if we feed these into equation (1) from above we get:

$$ \tan\phi = \frac{v}{c^2} $$

Schutz actually gives this as $\tan\phi = v$ because he's using the usual relativists' convention that $c = 1$ i.e. we express velocities as fractions of the speed of light.

To get the angle between the $t$ and $t'$ axes in the left diagram repeat the above but starting with the point $(t', 0)$. For the two angles in the right hand diagram transform $(0, x)$ and $(t, 0)$ to $S'$, remembering that $v$ is now positive. You'll find they are indeed all the same angle.